# Ambiguous reference to member

Tags: variables, swift3

I'm following a Youtube tutorial with firebase and I have exactly what the guy has, but it is not working for me. I get this error "Ambiguous reference to member 'count'"

Here's the code:

```
//declaration of variable
var stuffs = [AnyObject]()

//code in cell for row at index path function
//where i get the error
let stuff = stuffs[(self.stuffs.count - 1) - indexPath.row].value["text"] as! String
```

Comment: Does the tutorial use Swift 3? In any case `stuffs` should be more specific than `AnyObject`.

Comment: Include a more completion version of your code

Comment: no it uses swift 2.2

Comment: @vadian if im using it to append a snapshot from a firebase database how could i be more specific?

Comment: In Swift 3 the most unspecified type is `Any` rather than `AnyObject`. If it's an array of *snapshots* then declare it as an array of *snapshots*, give the compiler as much information as possible.

Comment: @vadian if i do that then i get the error "type 'any' has no subscription members" in reference to the .value i declared

Comment: You must also cast `value` to a dictionary. In Swift 3 the compiler needs to know the actual type of **all** subscripted objects. That is for security reasons to prevent runtime errors.

Comment: @vadian i did, still same error